# Batch file that copies a dynamic file name to a different directory with the date

Tags: csv, batch-file, file-rename, file-copying

Okay, we're trying to copy three files with different number of iterations to another folder with a date added after the file name. Here is our code:

```
@ECHO off
XCOPY /y /c z:\accounting\daily\test\fdxe*.csv

rem get date, make it file name friendly
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set d=%%j%%k%%l

set csv=fdxe*%d%.csv
ren fdxe*.csv %csv%
move fdxe*.csv \\newserver\Export\Fedex\test\
@ECHO on
```

Now it is copying the files to the proper folder, and it's adding the date but it keeps adding the date after the `.csv` extension. So we end up with: `fdxe1.csv01212016`.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use a FOR command to iterate all the files and use the command modifiers to break apart the base file name from the extension.

Comment: How would I do that? Batch file's are something I've had very little experience with.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem by moving the files over and then renaming them. I also changed the rename section using `?` instead of `*` for the characters I wanted it to keep in the original file name. The code now reads:

```
@ECHO off
XCOPY /y /c z:\accounting\daily\test\fdxe*.csv

move fdxe*.csv \\devserver\Elliott_Export\Fedex\test\

rem get date, make it file name friendly
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set d=%%j%%k%%l

rename \\newserver\Export\Fedex\test\?.??? ?????_%d%.???
@Echo on
```